# How to prevent a condition from being repeated in several navigation properties in lambda expressions or linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

When I map a DB entity to my DTO in the project, I create in a single model the properties of both the header and its related table of languages.
When repeating this condition in several properties, the query that generates is very large and makes me lose a lot of time in the query. How can I raise this to have to do the comparison only once?

```
return s => new DtoTimelineEvent()
        {
            Id = s.tline_even_id_i,
            TimelineId = s.tline_id_i,
            Tipo = (TimeLineEventTypes)s.even_tip_id_i,
            Fecha = s.fecha_dt,

            Titulo = s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.Any(a => a.idi_id_t == (byte)cultura) ? s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idi_id_t == (byte)cultura).Titulo : s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.FirstOrDefault().Titulo,
            Descripcion = s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.Any(a => a.idi_id_t == (byte)cultura) ? s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idi_id_t == (byte)cultura).Descripcion : s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.FirstOrDefault().Descripcion,

            SocialId = s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.Any(a => a.idi_id_t == (byte)cultura) ?
               s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idi_id_t == (byte)cultura).obj_id :
               s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.FirstOrDefault().obj_id,
        }
```

"Titulo", "Descripcion" and "SocialId" have the same condition and are repeated in many more fields, how can I improve this query?

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps: first, fetch the object on which `Titulo`, `Description`, and `SocialId` are defined, and then project them out:

```
return s => {
    var common = s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.Any(a => a.idi_id_t == (byte)cultura)
        ? s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.FirstOrDefault(a => a.idi_id_t == (byte)cultura)
        : s.t_tline_even_rel_idi.FirstOrDefault();
    return new DtoTimelineEvent() {
        Id = s.tline_even_id_i,
        TimelineId = s.tline_id_i,
        Tipo = (TimeLineEventTypes)s.even_tip_id_i,
        Fecha = s.fecha_dt,
        Titolo = common.Titolo,
        Description = common.Description,
        SocialId = common.obj_id
    };
};
```

This fetches `common` object only once, and then its fields are referenced in the constructor of DTO.

Comment: My problem is that this function goes inside a Queryable.Select (), so I have not yet gone to DB, it's building a Query.
If I use your solution it will call DB in each iteration

Comment: I need a solution that does not involve calling the database until I want to. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Jorge I thought the return is inside a bigger LINQ query. You can push it inside the same lambda, though.